# Using VLOOKUP and SUMIF for pending vs posted transactions

Tags: excel, vlookup, sumifs

Is there a way to use VLOOKUP and SUMIF in the same string?

Currently, what I have is a column that looks up an ID, finds it on my table on another sheet, and sums each value in my "Quantity" Column if the ID Match the lookup.

```
=SUMIF(OUT_TABLE[SAP ID], VLOOKUP(A2, Lookup_table, 1, FALSE), OUT_TABLE[Quantity])
```

Now I would like to add the "**Quantity**" Column ONLY if my Issuance column is not blank.

This is for an Inventory sheet that I would like to show posted transactions as well as pending transactions. If the transaction is posted, there will be a value in my "**Issuance**" Column. Otherwise, it has yet to be posted.

[Outbound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfvD7.png) Transaction going out with "Issuance" saying "Yes"

[Inventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chpkz.png) The transaction shows in "Outbound Posted". If blank in the "Issuance" column, then this transaction will show up in "Outbound Pending" or not show up at all in the "Outbound Posted"

Comment: You refer to the "Issuance column" but it's not entirely clear if that's represented by the first or second parameters in your `SUMIF` statement.  Can you show us a sample of these two tables, and highlight each mentioned throughout your question?

Comment: Thanks Gravity, my issuance column is not represented in my formula. I have added images to try and clear it up. Basically, if the Issuance column is blank, I want the transaction to be "pending"